# finding the exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem which has this equation

$$130 \cdot (0.07)^{n} = 100 \cdot (0.08637)^{n}$$

How can I find $n$?

Can anybody help me in solving this?

would really appreciate it, because I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if you take the logarithm of both sides, you get
$$
\log(130)+n\log(0.07)=\log(100)+n\log(0.08637)
$$

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!.  n= 1,25 ( more or less)

Answer (score 0):

$$130\cdot(0.07)^{n}=100\cdot(0.08637)^{n}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{130}{100}=\frac{(0.08637)^{n}}{(0.07)^{n}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{13}{10}=\left(\frac{0.08637}{0.07}\right)^n\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{13}{10}=\left(1.23386\right)^n\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$n=\log_{1.23386}\left(\frac{13}{10}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$n=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{13}{10}\right)}{\ln(1.23386)}$$